# Google Analytics Not tracking data correctly IP-address issue?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, analytics

I have developed a small site for a client and the site has been placed inside a `<iframe>` at the clients site. The GA-script I'm using looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(
  ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2'], //My company's GA-account
  ['_trackPageview'],
  ['b._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1'],  // Test GA-account
  ['b._trackPageview'],
  ['th._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-3'],
  ['th._setDomainName', '.clientdomain.se'], // Client GA-account
  ['th._trackPageview']
);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

    </script>
</head>
```

As you can see I report the GA pageviews to the client as well. The GA script is tracking visitors and pageviews at both ends. But the problem is that on my clients side the visitor-count is more than double what they are on my end (20 000 vs 5 000). At first I thought that it was being duplicated at some point but when I checked my Crazy-Egg account I saw that it had tracked over 10 000 visits and then stopped tracking because that was my limit on the account.

The page my site is on is on a IP-address (http://XXX.XXX.XX.X/campaign/) and not on a "valid url". Could that be an issue why some of the visitors isn't beeing tracked?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting the cookie domain to "none": `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);` - I know localhost is required and I'm pretty sure IP based pages are too.

Comment: @MisterPhilip Thank you for the reply but it did not seem to work.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @Blexy This is the frame-page: http://www.trygghansa.se/campaign/eurobonus/pages/tavling.aspx